# how to pass data to a kernel thread without taking global variable

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

how to pass a data to a kenel thread from a function without taking a global variable directly pass the data to the thread from a function which is different from that function where thread is created. 
thank you

Comment: If you are about **starting** kernel with some parameter, then function `kthread_create()` accepts `data` parameter, which is passed to the thread's function. You may set value of that parameter to your data (if it is a simple type like `int`). Or you may set value of that parameter to the *pointer* to your data. If you want "pass" some data a kernel thread when it is **already run**, then it is known as inter-process (or inter-thread) communication. There are many ways for such communication, and choosing one way or another depends on your needs. *Which case is yours?*

Comment: i need to pass data to already running thread not at the time of creation of the thread , but i am not getting what are the ways to communicate with the running thread in kenel space.

Comment: Hm, actually all kernel-thread communication mechanism which I know use some *global object*. Not sure, why you don't want it. Anyway, improve your question post with more details about your situation and problem. Currently, your problem's description is *too vague*.